# Need a fast random generator for c++

Tags: c++, random, performance

I'm trying to do some opt-3 swapping on my TSP generator for euclidian distances, and since I in many cases have more than ~500 nodes, I need to randomly select at least 1 of the 3 nodes that I want to try swapping.

So basically I need a random-number function that's **fast**. (the normal rand() is way too slow) It doesn't have to be awesome, just good *enough*.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention, i'm sitting at an environment where I can't add any libraries except the Standard Language Library (such as STL, iostream etc). So no boost =/